# How to change image tag to another tag in svg?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have image inside svg.

Each `<circle cx="30%" cy="30%" r="40px" style="transform-origin: 30% 30%" class="shape" />` reval parts in the image (for start is hidden by black background).

How to replace image tag with another tag like `img` or `div` or `iframe` or webcomponent and still have the same behavior to revael beneath it?

For example I want to have `<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/2">` but not in image tag. 
or `<my-awesome-img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/2">` which render the image with component styles and more.

```css
.some { height:100vh;width:100vw;}

.object-fit_contain {
  object-fit: contain;
}
.full-height {
  height: 100%;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
.full-height.two {
  background: #acacac;
}
.full-height.three {
  background: #5e5e5e;
}
.ex-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  .ex-peephole {
    position: absolute;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}

@keyframes shapeTransition {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.2);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
.shape {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: shapeTransition;
}
@keyframes fullImageTransition {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.2);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
.rect {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: fullImageTransition;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="some">
<svg style="background: black" fill="black" class="button" expanded="true" height="100%" width="100%">
   <defs>
     <clipPath ref="clipPath" id="theClipPath_1">
       <circle cx="30%" cy="30%" r="40px" style="transform-origin: 30% 30%" class="shape" />
       
     </clipPath>
   </defs>
   <g clip-path="url(#theClipPath_1)">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:rgb(255,255,255)" />
     <image
            preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"
            class="kid clipPathReveal"
            style="stroke-width: 0px; "
            href="https://source.unsplash.com/random/2"
            x="0"
            y="0"
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            />
   </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

I want the svg to look like this:
(I also try position absolute, and put the div outside the svg - but not works.)

```
<svg style="background: black" fill="black" class="button" expanded="true" height="100%" width="100%">
   <defs>
     <clipPath ref="clipPath" id="theClipPath_1">
       <circle cx="30%" cy="30%" r="40px" style="transform-origin: 30% 30%" class="shape" />

     </clipPath>
   </defs>
   <g clip-path="url(#theClipPath_1)">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:rgb(255,255,255)" />
     <div style="background:red;">blablabla</div>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: So you want to "replace IMG dynamically" or "replace IMG manually"?

Comment: instend of image I want to put another div or img or component. see my edit answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG contents are rendered based on namespaces where it defaults to XML when none is specified.

For you to be able to display html contents inside an SVG tag you need to wrap the html code within a `<foreignObject>` tag. The foreignObject tag allows embedding all kinds of markup, not just HTML. This means, there must be a way of determining what language is used. That's where namespaces come into play.

To tell SVG what kind of foreignObject it is, you have to put the content in the proper namespace. Based on your code a proper example would look like below:

```
<svg style="background: black" fill="black" class="button" 
 expanded="true" height="100%" width="100%">
  <defs>
    <clipPath ref="clipPath" id="theClipPath_1">
     <circle cx="30%" cy="30%" r="40px" style="transform-origin: 30% 30%" class="shape" />
    </clipPath>
 </defs>
 <g clip-path="url(#theClipPath_1)">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:rgb(255,255,255)" />
  <foreignObject x="40" y="40" width="100" height="100">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/2" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="100%" height="100%"/>
  </foreignObject>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Cool. but this div is getting very much height and width: seems that 100% not working. why?
`<foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"><div style="width:100%;height:100%;background:url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/2');background-position:;"></div></foreignObject>`

Comment: Use an absolute width or height in px for any of its parent not percentage %